# JavaFX TableView cell set value later

Tags: java, javafx, set, tableview, tablecell

I have a TableView with 4 rows and for each one a custom cell. The first one is just an image, which one I want to update a few times, a string, a string with word wrap and an second image as a button.

```
// image
tcUrlStatus.setCellValueFactory(new ColumnImageFactory());
tcUrlStatus.setCellFactory(new ColumnCallback());

// one line string
tcUrlName.setCellValueFactory(new ColumnNameFactory());
tcUrlName.setCellFactory(new ColumnCallback());

// two line string
tcUrlDate.setCellValueFactory(new ColumnDateFactory());
tcUrlDate.setCellFactory(new ColumnCallback());

// image as a button
tcDelete.setCellValueFactory(new ColumnDeleteFactory());
tcDelete.setCellFactory(new ColumnCallback());
```

And here are the custom cells

```
class ColumnCallback implements Callback<TableColumn<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object>, TableCell<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object>>{
    @Override
    public TableCell<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object> call(TableColumn<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object> column) {
        return new ColumnCell();
    }
}

class ColumnImageFactory implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Object, String, String, String>, String>, ObservableValue<Object>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Object> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Object, String, String, String>, String> data) {
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(data.getValue().getValue0());
    }
}

class ColumnNameFactory implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, String>, ObservableValue<String>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, String> data) {
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(data.getValue().getValue1());
    }
}

class ColumnDateFactory implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object>, ObservableValue<Object>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Object> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object> data) {
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(data.getValue().getValue2());
    }
}

class ColumnDeleteFactory implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object>, ObservableValue<Object>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Object> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object> data) {
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(data.getValue().getValue3());
    }
}

class ColumnCell extends TableCell<Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String>, Object> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item != null) {
            if (item instanceof Boolean) {
                setText(null);
                Image image;
                AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

                if ((boolean) item) {
                    image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/hourglass.gif"));
                } else {
                    image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/clean.gif"));
                }

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                imageView.setFitWidth(30);
                imageView.setY(5);
                imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                imageView.setSmooth(true);

                pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

                setGraphic(pane);
            }else {
                if (item instanceof String) {
                    if (item.equals("delete")) {
                        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

                        Image image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/cross.png"));

                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                        imageView.setFitWidth(20);
                        imageView.setY(10);
                        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                        imageView.setSmooth(true);
                        imageView.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

                        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

                        imageView.setOnMouseClicked((Event event) -> {
                            Quartet<Boolean, String, String, String> row = this.getTableView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                            Controller.localJson.remove(row.getValue1());
                            this.getTableView().getItems().remove(row);
                        });

                        setGraphic(pane);
                    } else {
                        HBox pane = new HBox();
                        Label label = new Label();
                        label.setText((String) item);

                        label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

                        if (((String) item).length() < 20) {
                            label.setWrapText(true);
                            label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                        }

                        pane.setPrefHeight(40);
                        label.setPrefHeight(40);
                        pane.getChildren().add(label);

                        setGraphic(pane);
                    }

                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        } else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the Image of the tcUrlStatus column/cell. I already figured out how to get the row or the value of it, but I can't figure out how to set the value or rather change from true to false or false to true for updating the image.

get row and value:

```
private int getTableRowIndex(String url){ // url is the second column
    int counter = 0;
    for (Object row:tvUrls.getItems()){
        if ((((Quartet) row).getValue1() == url)){
            return counter;
        }
        counter ++;
    }

    return -1;
}

int rowIndex = getTableRowIndex(url);
Object item = tvUrls.getItems().get(rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to do this by using javafx properties in your `Quartet` class, e.g. assuming the type used for the `value0` bean is `T`:

```
// TODO: Is using a readonly property really needed here ???
//       if not, use SimpleObjectProperty instead
private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<T> value0 = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

public T getValue0() {
     return value0.get();
}

// TODO: should the setter really be public ???
public void setValue0(T newValue) {
     value0.set(newValue);
}

public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<T> value0Property() {
    return value0.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

Which allows you to use [`new PropertyValueFactory<>("value0")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) instead of your custom cell value factory, and, even more important, means the `TableView` components will be notified of changes in the `Quartet` instances.

This way you can simply use

```
quartetInstance.setValue0(newValue0);
```

and the cell will get updated.

Using the `PropertyValueFactory` would have the same effect as using the following `cellValueFactory` in this case:

```
class ColumnImageFactory implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Object, String, String, String>, String>, ObservableValue<Object>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Object> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Quartet<Object, String, String, String>, String> data) {
        return data.getValue().value0Property();
    }
}
```

If you cannot add javaFX properties to the `Quartet` class you need some other way of updating the `TableView` after the change. `TableView.refresh()` would work (provided you use JavaFX version >= `8u60`) or writing [an adapter](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html) in case you have implemented the observer patten in the `Quartet` class some other way...

Comment: I didn't try it, but I solved the "problem" with another solution. I used SimpleObjectProperty. It's kind of cleaner than using the Quartet class. I will post it right in a second as my solution :)

Comment: @Mr.Tr33 Yup, usually you have items that contain properties and the `cellValueFactory`s return one of those properties instead of creating a new one; which the cells then display, whether the properties are readonly or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with chaning from the Quartet Class to the SimpleObjectProperty Class.

Init:

```
tcUrlStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ColumnCellValue, Boolean>("status"));
tcUrlName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ColumnCellValue, String>("url"));
tcUrlDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ColumnCellValue, String>("date"));
tcDelete.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ColumnCellValue, Boolean>("delete"));

tcUrlStatus.setCellFactory(new ColumnStatusCell());
tcUrlName.setCellFactory(new ColumnStringCell(false));
tcUrlDate.setCellFactory(new ColumnStringCell(true));
tcDelete.setCellFactory(new ColumnDeleteCell());
```

Adding rows:

```
tvUrls.getItems().add(new ColumnCellValue(true, url, date));
```

Updating cells:

```
ColumnCellValue statusRow = (ColumnCellValue)
tvUrls.getItems().get(rowIndex);
```

Column classes:

```
public class ColumnCellValue{
    private final ObjectProperty status;
    private final ObjectProperty url;
    private final ObjectProperty date;
    private final ObjectProperty delete = new SimpleObjectProperty<Boolean>(true);

    ColumnCellValue(Boolean status, String url, String date) {
        this.status = new SimpleObjectProperty<Boolean>(status);
        this.url = new SimpleObjectProperty<String>(url);
        this.date = new SimpleObjectProperty<String>(date);
    }

    public Object getDate() {
        return date.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty dateProperty() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Object date) {
        this.date.set(date);
    }

    public Object getDelete() {
        return delete.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty deleteProperty() {
        return delete;
    }

    public void setDelete(Object delete) {
        this.delete.set(delete);
    }

    public Object getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty statusProperty() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Object status) {
        this.status.set(status);
    }

    public Object getUrl() {
        return url.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty urlProperty() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(Object url) {
        this.url.set(url);
    }
}

class ColumnStatusCell implements Callback<TableColumn<Boolean, Boolean>,TableCell<Boolean, Boolean>>{
    @Override
    public TableCell<Boolean, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Boolean, Boolean> param) {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitWidth(30);
        imageView.setY(5);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);

        TableCell<Boolean,Boolean> cell = new TableCell<Boolean,Boolean>(){
            public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                if(item!=null){
                    Image image;

                    if (item) {
                        image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/hourglass.gif"));
                    } else {
                        image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/clean.gif"));
                    }

                    imageView.setImage(image);
                }
            }
        };

        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        cell.setGraphic(pane);

        return cell;
    }
}

class ColumnStringCell implements Callback<TableColumn<String, String>,TableCell<String, String>>{
    private boolean wrap = false;

    ColumnStringCell(boolean wrap){
        this.wrap = wrap;
    }

    @Override
    public TableCell<String, String> call(TableColumn<String, String> param) {
        TableCell<String,String> cell = new TableCell<String,String>(){
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                if(item!=null){
                    Label label = new Label();
                    label.setText(item);
                    label.setPrefHeight(40);
                    label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

                    label.setWrapText(wrap);

                    setGraphic(label);
                }
            }
        };

        return cell;
    }
}

class ColumnDeleteCell implements Callback<TableColumn<Boolean, Boolean>,TableCell<Boolean, Boolean>>{
    @Override
    public TableCell<Boolean, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Boolean, Boolean> param) {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitWidth(20);
        imageView.setY(10);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);
        imageView.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

        TableCell<Boolean,Boolean> cell = new TableCell<Boolean,Boolean>(){
            public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                if (item != null) {
                    Image image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/cross.png"));
                    imageView.setImage(image);
                }
            }
        };

        imageView.setOnMouseClicked((Event event) -> {
            TableView table = (TableView) ((ImageView) event.getSource()).getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
            ColumnCellValue row = (ColumnCellValue) (table).getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

            Controller.localJson.remove(row.getUrl().toString());
            table.getItems().remove(row);

            table.refresh();
        });

        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        cell.setGraphic(pane);

        return cell;
    }
}
```